# Google IAM adding additional owner to project not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'm currently trying to invite another developer to my `gcloud` project as an owner. For this I go inside the `IAM` and grant him access via his gmail account. He receives the invitation e-mail, clicks on "accept invitation" and then has full access rights on the project. However in the IAM it still says:`"Invitation sent. Pending acceptance."`.

In consequence he's not able to deploy any new `AppEngine` builds as `gcloud` CLI fails reporting he does not have the necessary access rights. Anyone experience the same issue? I already checked the e-mail address multiple times as well as wait for several days (so permissions are properly set), but nothing changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While waiting or solving the email invite, assign normal resource-based IAM roles granting permission.

Except for special cases, the Owner role should not be used or granted to users.

You, as project owner, should not be using an account with the Owner role. That role should be assigned to an identity that is locked away for use when required.